# Direct Comparison Test - Did I solve this correctly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been trying to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if I'm correct.
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{sin(n)}{n^2+\sqrt{n}}$$

Here is what I've done so far:

I need to find whether it converges or diverges, so I'm using the Direct Comparison Test.

On the interval [1, ∞], sin(n) < 1.

So, the new sequence is: $$b_n=\frac{1}{n^2+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^2} \ge a_n$$
This is convergent because p > 1.

So, since the larger series converges, so must the smaller one.
Did I do this right?

Comment: Note $|\sin n|\leq 1$ for all real $n$. Also, $ \frac{1}{n^2+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^2}\geq a_n $ is not true

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test for the statement of the direct comparison test. You need to account for the sign of the summand too in general.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea but there are some typos. To show convergence it suffices to show absolute convergence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2+\sqrt{n}}=L<\infty. $$

Now we note that $|\sin n |\leq 1$ and $n^2+\sqrt n>n^2$ so

$$\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

and since $\sum_n 1/n^2$ converges, we are done.

Comment: Thank you! I used that test instead.